# Using a separate application as an asmx webservice

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, entity-framework

I have been asked at my internship to create a web service using Entity Framework. They told me to start off by creating a separate application that can be later integrated into the main application. If i have the separate application made, how do I integrate it into the existing one?

I looked around and it looks like everybody just creates the webservice inside the application itself?

Comment: Take a look at N-Tier application

Comment: If your internship is using ASMX web services, then you should look for a different internship. That's a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: with all due respect, i beg to defer still. but we have had this argument before :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887813/does-net-4-0-still-support-asmx

Comment: @naveen: with all due respect, I wasn't talking to you. I actually upvoted your answer, BTW.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: sorry if i have offended you. :) IMHO noobs should not be having too much complications when they start programming...

Comment: @naveen: you haven't offended me. I don't happen to see how it's a "complication" to use current technology instead of ancient technology. What's the point of a new developer using a technology that should not be used for new development?

Answer (score 1):

No way. Your assumption is way off. Web Services were originally designed to be called from remote, as a service. .NET uses asmx a lot is the same application to simplify AJAX calls and thats why you see those a lot.

Just host a web-service and call that in your application. It is simpler than you think.
First try calling some web-service from http://webservicex.net/ws/default.aspx and then create one of your own to make things easy for you.

Comment: I guess the part where I'm stuck is implementing the webservice into the project itself. I have the edmx file as well as some methods in the Module1.vb file. How do I go about accessing these from the main project? I see alot of information on WCF web services, however I was asked to use asmx web services.